# wrong results of the function gsl_cdf_ugaussian_Pinv

Tags: gsl

I run this program:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    double x= 0.5;
    double res = gsl_cdf_ugaussian_Pinv(x);
    printf("icdf(%f)=%f\n",x,res);
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason the output is: **icdf(0.500000)=1.000000**

Which is wrong, it should be: **icdf(0.500000)=0.000000**

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[The inverse cumulative distributions, x=P^{-1}(P) and x=Q^{-1}(Q) give the values of x which correspond to a specific value of P or Q. They can be used to find confidence limits from probability values.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Distribution-Introduction.html#Random-Number-Distribution-Introduction)

I think, that this is a correct output.

Comment: but if X is standard Gaussian then P(X<0)=0.5 therefore Pinv(0.5)=0

Answer (score 0):

The header file `gsl/gsl_math.h` doesn't include the prototypes for the probability distribution functions.  This means the compiler hasn't seen a declaration of `gsl_cdf_ugaussian_Pinv(x)`, so it thinks the function returns an integer.  When I compile your code, I get a warning about this, and when I run it, I get:

```
icdf(0.500000)=256835073.000000
```

which is obviously wrong.  When I change this

```
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
```

to

```
#include <gsl/gsl_cdf.h>
```

the file compiles with no warning, and gives:

```
icdf(0.500000)=0.000000
```

as expected.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Distribution-Examples.html#Random-Number-Distribution-Examples for another example (scroll down to the bottom).